# Como mesclar códigos do GitHub?

Tags: git, spring-boot

Eu baixei um projeto do GitHub, em seguida fiz uma alterações, um outro colega meu fez a mesma coisa com uma única diferença, ele fez um commit e atualizou o repositório no GitHub. Eu precisei criar um Branch e fazer um merge e em seguida eu fiz um `git pull origin master`

O STS me mostrou algumas incoexistências, e é possível realizar comparações das minhas alterações com o código vindo do repositório como pode ver abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por favor, eu gostaria de saber se existe algum recurso no STS para conseguir mesclar os dois códigos?

Comment: está usando qual plugin de git? O EGit?

Comment: Por favor , como vou usar isso para mesclar os dois códigos?

Comment: Na experiência que tenho trabalhando com git, quando ele faz o merge e não consegue resolver os conflitos automaticamente, vc deve ir "selecionando" o trecho do código válido.

Answer (score -2):

Me parece que ele já está apresentando uma forma de fazer merge. Você vai ter que mesclar os códigos na mão mesmo, nem sempre um merge rola liso, sem ter que selecionar o que vai para a sua main branch.

Eu particularmente uso o meld para fazer merge, ele é bom e independente de IDE. Se você optar pelo meld ou qualquer outra ferramenta que faça merge, basta você definir no .gitconfig ou mesmo através de comando.

```
# set up Meld as the default gui diff tool
$ git config --global  diff.guitool meld

# set the path to Meld
$ git config --global mergetool.meld.path C:/meld-1.6.0/Bin/meld.sh
```

Então é só usar o comando abaixo por exemplo:

```
git merge origin/master
```

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score -2):

Boa noite @user10264, para vocês não terem problema  no mesmo projeto. Recomendável caso o repositório seja de sua propriedade ou do seu colegar. Seria proteger a branch principal. Isso você consegue indo nas configurações de projeto no github. Você e ele criar uma branch separada para trabalhar nesse projeto. Quando for atualizar o branch principal utilizar o merge do github, para aprovar as atualizações para principal.

Dessa maneira, quando ele for enviar atualizações vai para branch dele, a partir da branch dele o merge com atualizações vai para principal. Nessa branch sua diferente da principal utilizar o `git pull --rebase origin master`, se caso der conflito com sua branch atual com a principal, você consegue corrigir. Logo em seguida subir suas alterações na branch que está trabalhando. Depois dar um merge  pelo github, como você está trabalhando.

Procurando algo para STS, não achei precisão mais se usar o mesmo que eclipse. Deve atender sua pergunta, [Merging branches in Eclipse git (EGit)](https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2011/05/30/merging-branches-in-eclipse-git-egit/).